# Mobile Gestalt Support Error on iOS app using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am getting the following error on my project and I am not sure what is causing it.

```
2017-04-04 10:28:39.243789-0500 GBus3[797:148184] libMobileGestalt 
MobileGestaltSupport.m:153: pid 797 (GBus3) does not have sandbox access for 
frZQaeyWLUvLjeuEK43hmg and IS NOT appropriately entitled
2017-04-04 10:28:39.243948-0500 GBus3[797:148184] libMobileGestalt 
MobileGestalt.c:550: no access to InverseDeviceID (see 
<rdar://problem/11744455>)
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2017-04-04 10:28:43.106075-0500 GBus3[797:148184] fatal error: unexpectedly 
found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I believe the error occurs when using a segue to switch between view controllers.

this is the code to execute the segue

```
func didTapTrackButton () {

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "HomeToTrack", sender: self)
}
```

This is the code for loading the second view controller

```
override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
    // Building a view
    let screenFrame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let contentView = UIView(frame: screenFrame)

    // Add Map
    self.mapView = MKMapView(frame: screenFrame)
    self.mapView.delegate = self
    contentView.addSubview(self.mapView)

    // Set Tracking
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    self.mapView.setUserTrackingMode(MKUserTrackingMode.follow, animated: true)

    // Set the built view as our view
    self.view = contentView
}
```

Comment: Please include the *relevant* part of your code in the question including a clear indication in what line the error occurs.

Comment: The compiler does not say where the error occurs. After using breakpoints I found it is when there is a switch between view controllers, which I have added

Comment: Oddly enough this exact same message started showing up in the output for our app - assuming it has something to do with 10.3.1.  We're presenting a UIWebView with NSData as the source in a dispatch_async.  No idea (yet) which of these are responsible for the log entry

Comment: I also see this error, (first 2 lines of your log) in a scenekit app on 10.3.1 . Looks like Apple did not update their own libraries, and it's not caused by any user code. The third one, your fatal error, I don't get.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [libMobileGestalt MobileGestaltSupport.m:153 MobileGestalt.c:550 Xcode Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43227082/libmobilegestalt-mobilegestaltsupport-m153-mobilegestalt-c550-xcode-console)