# libMobileGestalt MobileGestaltSupport.m:153 MobileGestalt.c:550 Xcode Console

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios10

I am getting Following messages on Xcode Console View

- libMobileGestalt MobileGestaltSupport.m:153: pid 231 (myproject) does
  not have sandbox access for frZQaeyWLUvLjeuEK43hmg and IS NOT
  appropriately entitled
- libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:550: no access to InverseDeviceID
  (see )

---

MacOs Sierra Version: 10.12.4
Xcode Version 8.3
Programming Language : Objective C

I get this message after application launch, Device is plugged with xcode while running the application. It seems like a rare issue. Anyone can help me to solve this?

Comment: Have your fixed the issue ? also does the application still run fine even with the messages in the console ?

Comment: I see the same libMobileGestalt messages in Xcode Console View when I run all my apps using Google AdMob Framework, on my real test device iPhone 6S Plus. No messages when I use simulator. I think the reason is not missing sandbox. Just some framework are deprecated.. So, have you find the reason, fix?

Comment: I just updated to iOS 10.3.2 and MacOs Sierra Version 10.12.5 and immediately got these messages. Probably just a bug

Comment: @Minestrone-Soup I don't think so it's a bug. need to find why this happening, I am still facing same issue. Unable to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue:

> 2017-08-04 12:02:44.936288+0100 Demos[1112:472604] libMobileGestalt MobileGestaltSupport.m:153: pid 1112 (Demos) does not have sandbox access for frZQaeyWLUvLjeuEK43hmg and IS NOT appropriately entitled
>
> 2017-08-04 12:02:44.936524+0100 Demos[1112:472604] libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:550: no access to InverseDeviceID (see )
>
> 2017-08-04 12:02:44.970997+0100 Demos[1112:472749] [INFO] {DefaultFileSource}[Database]: cannot open file at line 38277 of [0e5ffd9123] (Code 14)
>
> 2017-08-04 12:02:44.971157+0100 Demos[1112:472749] [INFO] {DefaultFileSource}[Database]: [0e5ffd9123]:38277: (0) open(/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/735DAEF4-D6F0-4565-A89E-4FA3A377485B/Library/Application Support/navenio.Demos/.mapbox/cache.db) -  (Code 14)

Finally I followed the link indicated there: [rdar://problem/11744455](http://rdar://problem/11744455) and it pointed me in the right direction. In my case, it had to do with user's permissions to use their location:

> I've managed to solve the same problem for MKMapView. Apparently, that happens when your app's current permissions state doesn't correspond to entitled (declared in Info.plist) one. That effecively means that you need to call APIs to gather user's permissions explicitly and preemptively. (E.g. LocationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization before displaying a map with user location on it)

Maybe your situation is different. But still ,there's a bunch of cases covered in that link.

Comment: this link is broken -> rdar://problem/11744455

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue, it turns out to be issue with multithreading.

Multiple threads was accessing the same piece of data (to be exact, `EAGLContext`, and some OpenGL stuffs) and probably messed up the memory.
The issue is gone after making sure accesses are synchronised.

Answer (score 0):

**Update #1:**

Additionally, I found that the same message appeared in later builds but crashes were associated with invalid Outlets in my storyboard that needed to be renamed or unlinked from the storyboard/controller: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',...`

**Original Response**

In my case, I started seeing this issue after adding Firebase pods into my application. After some debugging with a fresh stub, I fixed my issue by adding the custom Google-Sign-In URL Scheme to my projects `URL Types` at the bottom of the info pane.

As noted in the instructions:

1. From your `GoogleService-Info.plist`, copy the value from the
   `REVERSED_CLIENT_ID` key
2. Click on your blue project file
3. Go to the Info Section on the Project Pane
4. At the bottom of the pane, Add a new URL Type and paste the copied
   text into the `URL Schemes` field

([Source](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating#add_a_url_scheme_to_your_project), Google Instructions)[image: 1000-words]

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same issue when trying to display the **GoogleMap** using GMSMapView. but it is just a warning (I still don't know how to get rid of it). What i wanted to say is the **Google Map view display and functionality works fine with this warning too.** (I checked in IOS 10.3)

check if you are trying to display the map in a subview there is a separate way to display (This is an easy guide i found - http://www.ryanwright.me/cookbook/ios/obj-c/maps/gmap/subview)

otherwise try

> self.view = gmsMapView;

Comment: From my point of view the Issue about 3 rd party library integration, That cause Xcode console to show this message. I may or not correct. But there is some solution I am still debugging...

Comment: I assume that issue wasn't caused by a 3rd party library. Because i have checked this with a new clean project (only with map view and simple map code) but still got this warning and worked fine