# libMobileGestalt MobileGestaltSupport.m:153: pid 1668 does not have sandbox access in Xcode console

Tags: xcode, entitlements

I'm seeing this message in the Xcode console whenever I run the app:
`libMobileGestalt MobileGestaltSupport.m:153: pid 1668 (APP_NAME) does not have sandbox access for frZQaejlsahdhlemg and IS NOT appropriately entitled`

Comment: I am also seeing this 

MobileGestaltSupport.m:153: pid 7550 (APP_NAME) does not have sandbox access for frZQaeyWLUvLjeuEK43hmg and IS NOT appropriately entitled

Comment: Any idea on why that happen? And will that cause crash?

Comment: I'm still looking into it @user6539552

Comment: Any solution to this ?

Comment: @Marin after digging into it, I found that embedding a view controller in a navigation controller is the main reason to show this error message. I tried to change some attributes to get rid of it, but I failed. If you ever fixed it, please share your thoughts. Thanks!

Comment: Same problem  -  PanGesture[1403:530065] libMobileGestalt MobileGestaltSupport.m:153: pid 1403 (PanGesture) does not have sandbox access for frZQaeyWLUvLjeuEK43hmg and IS NOT appropriately entitled
Does not seem to affect the running of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging into it, I found that embedding a UIViewController -*or any subclass of it*- in a navigation controller is the main reason to show this error message.
I'm not sure what exactly makes the navigation controller show this message.

**Edit 1:**

After Xcode 9, I'm not seeing this issue anymore with new projects created in Xcode 9

**Edit 2:**

In Xcode 9, I saw the same error when working with CGRect.

Comment: So, have you fixed or not? 
I see the same libMobileGestalt messages in Xcode Console View when I run all my apps using Google AdMob Framework, on my real test device iPhone 6S Plus. No messages when I use simulator. I think the reason is that some framework are deprecated..

Comment: I'm still stuck at this problem, did you just remove that nav controller?

Comment: @Edu Actually I removed it only for testing as this problem is not affecting me. However, this issue is no longer exists in Xcode 9. Check the new edit in the answer.

Comment: @MEnnabah really appreciate your answer, so it's time to upgrade to Xcode 9 :)

Comment: @Edu Yeah actually it's super fast, I started using it since day 0

Comment: @Edu, please check Edit 2

Answer (score 2):

Using Apache Cordova, in my case, I had the same issue, and after some deep searches, I found it was originally (and stupidly) due to Splashscreen.

Check/add these lines in your **config.xml** file :

```
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
<feature name="SplashScreen">
    <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVSplashScreen" />
</feature>
```

And then my app worked like a charm. 
Hope this helps in your case.

Comment: For Cordova running in a webview this does not remove the log line that the original question mentions, but it seems to resolve a random startup issue that results in a incorrect init and fails to send "deviceready". Probably the problem is a underlying race condition "fixed" by different startup timing. The preferences can be omitted and onload can be set to false. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43227082/libmobilegestalt-mobilegestaltsupport-m153-mobilegestalt-c550-xcode-console?rq=1