# Google Maps not working in real device iOS Swfit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps

I have an app which has a screen using google maps and it's working in the simulator perfectly but when i am trying to run the app in a real device (iphone 5s) with ios 10.3 app running but it's crash when i go to any screen with using google maps

and getting this error

```
2017-08-14 00:44:48.425934+0200 MyApp[3603:866147] libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:550: no access to InverseDeviceID (see <rdar://problem/11744455>)
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2017-08-14 00:44:48.678827+0200 Carwash[3603:866147] fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

[image: ERROR Screenshot]

and here's my code :

**Appdelegate :**

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("MyApiKey")

        return true
    }
```

**Map In view Controller :**

```
import GoogleMaps
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Vars 

    var locManager = CLLocationManager()
    var currentLocation: CLLocation!
    var coordinates:CLLocationCoordinate2D!


    // MARK- Outlets 

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


        setUpMap()




    }


// MARK: - set up map 


    func  setUpMap()
    {
        //Location Manager code to fetch current location
        self.locManager.delegate = self
        self.locManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        currentLocation = locManager.location
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude:currentLocation.coordinate.latitude,longitude: currentLocation.coordinate.longitude, zoom: 14)


        let marker = GMSMarker(position : CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude:  currentLocation.coordinate.longitude))
        marker.map = mapView
        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
        mapView.delegate = self
       self.mapView.camera = camera
        self.coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)



    }



}



// Mark: -CLLocationManagerDelegate
extension HomeViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate , GMSMapViewDelegate {



    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
            locManager.startUpdatingLocation()

            mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
            mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let location = locations.first {
            mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: location.coordinate, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)

            locManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

        }
    }



}
```

anybody know what's wrong  ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43227082/libmobilegestalt-mobilegestaltsupport-m153-mobilegestalt-c550-xcode-console/44970665#44970665 (all the proposed answers)

Comment: In your error it says see: https://openradar.appspot.com/11744455...so it *seems* to be a known issue.

Comment: @nathan that what i have done ?

Comment: *fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value*
please check it again

Comment: it's working in simulator but not in a real device ?